# How can I get the user object from a service in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

My site is using a third party service for authentication as well as other bits of functionality so I have setup a service that does all the API calls for me and it's this service that I need to be able to access the user object.
I've tried injecting the security.context service into my API service but I get a ServiceCircularReferenceException because my user authentication provider references the API service (it has to in order to authenticate the user).
So I get a chain of

```
security.context -> authentication provider -> 
user provider -> API service -> security.context
```

I'm struggling to this of another way of getting the user object and I can't see any obvious way of splitting up this chain.

My configs are all defined in config.yml, here are the relevant bits

```
myapp.database:
    class: Pogo\MyAppBundle\Service\DatabaseService
    arguments:
        siteid: %siteid%
        entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
myapp.apiservice:
    class: Pogo\MyAppBundle\Service\TicketingService
    arguments:
        entityManager: "@myapp.database"
myapp.user_provider:
    class: Pogo\MyAppBundle\Service\APIUserProvider
    arguments:
        entityManager: "@myapp.database"
        ticketingAdapter: "@myapp.apiservice"
        securityContext: "@security.context"
myapp.authenticationprovider:
    class: Pogo\MyAppBundle\Service\APIAuthenticationProvider
    arguments:
        userChecker: "@security.user_checker"
        encoderFactory: "@security.encoder_factory"
        userProvider: "@myapp.user_provider"
```

myapp.user_provider is the service that I've defined as my user provider service in security.yml which I presume is how it's being referenced by security.context

Comment: How are you defining your custom service in services.xml or services.yml or even in config.yml?  Seeing your config will help.

Comment: I've updated my example so it's a bit more descriptive of my problem, do you have any ideas or alternatively do you know of another way of checking if a user has logged in other that via security.context?

Answer (score 1):

The `security.context` service has too many responsibilities. This is why it was deprecated in Symfony 2.6 and two new services took its place; `security.token_storage` and `security.authorization_checker`. Updating might solve some of your headaches.

Read more here: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements

And aslo: Why does the user provider need a security context? A UserProvider should only load a user by its username. Nothing more... Read more about custom user providers here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary workaround, but it's not very kosher. You can inject whole `@service_container` to your service and use just `security.context` from it. However, you have to set whole container as class property. If you take just security context in constructor, it'll still throw you circular reference exception.